# 家庭内の全体の電力データと３つの家電製品の電力から全体の電力データを予測

Tags: python, keras

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/235/individual+household+electric+power+consumption

上記のサイトから取得できるデータセットを用いて電力データの「時系列予測」を行っていて、 `'Global_active_power', 'Sub_metering_1', 'Sub_metering_2', 'Sub_metering_3'` の４つのデータから
`'Global_active_power'` の予測を行いたくPython環境でKerasのライブラリのLSTMを使い「時系列予測」を行っているのですが、４つのデータから１つのデータの予測のやり方がわからないです。
現在のコードが以下のようになっています。４つのデータから４つをそのまま予測しているようです。
どのようにしたら４つのデータから１つのデータを予測できるでしょうか。ご教授してもらえると幸いです。

参考にしているのは以下のサイトです。
https://www.kaggle.com/code/yassinesfaihi/lstm-time-series-household-power-consumption

時刻 `t-1` から `t-5` の間の `'Global_active_power', 'Sub_metering_1', 'Sub_metering_2', 'Sub_metering_3'` の計４つのデータから、時刻 `t` の `'Global_active_power'` を予測したいと思っています。

```
# Import necessary libraries and packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Set floating point precision option for pandas
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.4f' % x)

# Import seaborn library and set context and style
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.3)
sns.set_style('white')

# Import warnings and set filter to ignore warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# Import time library
from time import time

# Import matplotlib ticker and scipy stats
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
from scipy import stats

# Import statistical tools for time series analysis
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

# Import preprocessing from sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Import partial autocorrelation function from statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import pacf

# Enable inline plotting in Jupyter Notebook
%matplotlib inline

# Import math library
import math

# Import necessary functions from keras
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import *

# Import MinMaxScaler from sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Import mean squared error and mean absolute error from sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

# Import early stopping from keras callbacks
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

#結果の読み出し(前回の続きから出力)
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Research_folder/Data_set/Data_set_from_UCI/household_power_consumption_Edited.csv')
data.head(5)

dataset = data.loc[:,['Global_active_power','Sub_metering_1','Sub_metering_2','Sub_metering_3']]

dataset = dataset.values.astype('float32')

#Create an instance of the MinMaxScaler class to scale the values between 0 and 1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

#Fit the MinMaxScaler to the transformed data and transform the values
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.80)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    X, Y = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        X.append(a)
        Y.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(X), np.array(Y)

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 30
X_train, Y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
X_test, Y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))

# Defining the LSTM model
model = Sequential()

# Adding the first layer with 100 LSTM units and input shape of the data
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))

# Adding a dropout layer to avoid overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a dense layer with 1 unit to make predictions
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compiling the model with mean squared error as the loss function and using Adam optimizer
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Fitting the model on training data and using early stopping to avoid overfitting
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=1240, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4)], verbose=1, shuffle=False)

# Displaying a summary of the model
model.summary()

# make predictions
train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
test_predict = model.predict(X_test)


pad_col = np.zeros(dataset.shape[1]-1)
def pad_array(val):
    return np.array([np.insert(pad_col, 0, x) for x in val])

train_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(pad_array(train_predict))
Y_train = scaler.inverse_transform(pad_array(Y_train))
test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(pad_array(test_predict))
Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(pad_array(Y_test))

aa=[x for x in range(200)]
# Creating a figure object with desired figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))

plt.tick_params(labelsize=20)

# Plotting the actual values in blue with a dot marker
plt.plot(aa, Y_test[0][:200], marker='.', label="actual", color='purple')

# Plotting the predicted values in green with a solid line
plt.plot(aa, test_predict[:,0][:200], '-', label="prediction", color='red')

# Removing the top spines
sns.despine(top=True)

# Adjusting the subplot location
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07)

# Labeling the y-axis
plt.ylabel('Global_active_power', size=22)

# Labeling the x-axis
plt.xlabel('Time step', size=22)

# Adding a legend with font size of 15
plt.legend(fontsize=22)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: 「４つのデータから１つのデータの予測のやり方がわからない」と書かれていますが、タイトルにある「３つの家電製品の電力から全体の電力データを予測」ですと説明変数は3つになり合わないです。

Comment: やりたい事は「時系列予測」で合ってますか？

Comment: 全体の電力データと加えて３つの家電製品の電力データの計４つを説明変数にして全体の電力データを予測したいと思っています。
やりたいことは「時系列予測」であっています。すみません説明不足でした。

Comment: X_train, Y_trainのshapeはどうなっていますか？

Comment: X_trainが(1639393, 1, 30)、Y_trainが(1639393, )になっています。

Comment: 参考サイトを見てもXのshapeは(1639393, 30)なのですが、敢えて(1639393, 1, 30)にしていますか？そうでないならX_train作成のコードを見直してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 参考サイトの101セルを見落としていました。失礼しました。

Comment: 参考サイトで下記のようにX_trainのshapeを直しているので敢えて(1639393, 1, 30)にしています。
`# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]`

`X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))`

`X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))`

見辛く申し訳ございません。

Comment: 「４つのデータから４つをそのまま予測しているようです。」というのは何をもってそう判断していますか？

Comment: 入力のデータを`'Global_active_power'`, `'Sub_metering_1'`, `'Sub_metering_2'`, `'Sub_metering_3'`の４つにして学習させた後の出力データを`'Global_active_power'`と`'time step'`のデータのみにしたいのですが、現在のコードでは`'Global_active_power'`, `'Sub_metering_1'`, `'Sub_metering_2'`, `'Sub_metering_3'`の４つのデータと`'time step'`のデータが出力されてしまい、それぞれ個別で予測して出力していると考え判断しました。

Comment: モデルの最終層が「model.add(Dense(1))」ならば出力は1つかと思うのですが、実際には4次元の出力であるということですか？

Comment: はい！そういうことです。説明下手で申し訳ないです。

Comment: test_predict = model.predict(X_test)のshapeが4次元ということですか？

Comment: pad_array関数は何をしている関数でしょうか？

Comment: scaler.inverse_transformでエラーにならないように0埋めしてるんですね。でもそれなら、有効な値はやはり1次元ではないですか？

Comment: 有効な値が１次元というのは最後の結果の出力の部分でしょうか

Comment: 「test_predict = model.predict(X_test)」を実行後のtest_predictは1次元のデータですよね？そうであればモデルの出力は質問者さんの希望通りの1つだと思いますが。

Comment: すみません、前回の質問で表現が間違っていたと思うので訂正したいと思います。
出力されている結果は多分１次元データであっていますが、４つのデータがそれぞれ出力されてしまっていて。思った通りの結果になっていないということです。

Comment: それは「Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(pad_array(Y_test))」のコードを実行した結果ですよね？ここから必要なデータだけ取り出せば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: それだと`'Sub_metering_1', 'Sub_metering_2', 'Sub_metering_3'`の３つが`'Global_active_power'`の説明変数として扱われていないと思ったのですが。
違うのでしょうか？

Comment: 「test_predict = model.predict(X_test)」のコードにて「X_test」が入力データですので、'Global_active_power','Sub_metering_1','Sub_metering_2','Sub_metering_3'の4つが説明変数になっていると思います。